# Objective C: Can I set a subview to be firstResponder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, first-responder

I have a situation whereby I am adding a view from another viewcontroller to an existing viewcontroller. For example:

```
//set up loading page
self.myLoadingPage = [[LoadingPageViewController alloc]init ];
self.myLoadingPage.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
self.myLoadingPage.view.hidden = YES;

[self.view addSubview:self.myLoadingPage.view];
```

Is it possible to set 'self.myLoadingPage' to be the first responder? This is the case whereby the loadingpage view size does not cover the entire size of the existing view and users can still interact with the superview (which is not the desired behaviour). I want to just enable the subview in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  I found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946147/why-is-uiview-exclusivetouch-property-not-blocking) with a quote from the Apple Developer Forums on this issue:

> To truly make this view the only thing
>   on screen that can receive touches
>   you'd need to either add another view
>   over top of everything else to catch
>   the rest of the touches, or subclass a
>   view somewhere in your hierarchy (or
>   your UIWindow itself) and override
>   hitTest:withEvent: to always return
>   your text view when it's visible, or
>   to return nil for touches not in your
>   text view.

This would seem to indicate there isn't a terribly straightforward solution (unless there was an API change regarding this made after October, 2010.)

Alternatively, I suppose you could go through all the other `subviews` in your `superview` and individually set their `userInteractionEnabled` properties to `NO` (but that would probably prove more cumbersome than the quoted solutions).

I would love to see other ways to allow this.

Answer (score 3):

When I had a similar problem, I made an invisible UIView that covered the entire screen, I added the large invisible UIView on top of the main view and made the loading view a subview of the invisible UIView.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to override hitTest method in your loading view to return TRUE. This top view is first in the responder chain, the hitTest method gets called which NORMALLY returns TRUE if the point is within the view and will therefore be handled, returning TRUE regardless means you get the touch event and effectively block the message being resent to the next responder.