# GLTapLabel Inside UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I'm using `GLTapLabel` to display my text in my `UITableView`. It will have some links I can click on as `GLTapLabels`, but when I click those links the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` fires. So how can I detect the click action in those links?

Comment: Are these static or dynamically loaded cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:) and return `nil` for any row you don't want to be selected.

> **Return Value**
>   An index-path object that confirms or alters the selected row. Return an NSIndexPath object other than indexPath if you want another cell to be selected. Return nil if you don't want the row selected.

For example, to only prevent selection in the first section:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
         return nil;
    }

    return indexPath;
}
```

---

You can also try setting `exclusiveTouch` on the `GLTapLabel` or overriding its `hitTest:withEvent:` as described in the answer to [Why is UIView exclusiveTouch property not blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946147/why-is-uiview-exclusivetouch-property-not-blocking).

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. I gonna try your solution soon and let you know if I have another issues.

Comment: Hi, I try doing as your advices and it seems I cannt click links and the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: also doesnt fire. What I want is when I click outside the links, the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: will fire, and click in the links it will do something. Can u help me fix it? Thank you in advanced.