# Which is the best solution for display links, hot words within UITextView/UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to make some words in `UILabel`/`UITextView` become links so people can click it (like phone numbers, web links, usernames... etc).

I have tried using `UIWebView` but it loads texts too slow, not fast as a simple `UILabel`/`UITxtView` so I decided not use `UIWebView`.

I searched for many custom `UILabel` to do that and I found `GLTapLabel` which I think is the easiest way. But `GLTapLabel` only supports 2 types of links, it detects words which start by "#" and "@" (I want to create more types like phone numbers, web links ..etc). And 1 more issue is if I click a `GLTapLabel`'s link insides a `UITableView` it will fire `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` (I also asked in here [GLTapLabel Inside UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764931/gltaplabel-inside-uitableview?noredirect=1#comment22668262_15764931) but not solved yet).

So can you guys give me some advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For arbitrary links your best bet is to use [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel), a subclass of `UILabel` that displays attributed strings on iOS 5.  If you are using iOS 6+, `UILabel` supports attributed strings directly.

```
TTTAttributedLabel *someLabel;
[someLabel addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someURLString] 
              withRange:[longerTextString rangeOfString:linkTextString]];


#pragma mark - TTTAttributedLabel Delegate

- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // handle the URL somehow
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does TTTAtributedLabel help me create any type of link I want? Actually I dont know whether those links can act like buttons (click it and my app will move to another screen...). 100% sure I will try it and let you know soon if I have some new problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `UITextView`'s `dataDetectorTypes`. This will allow you to have links for URLs and other types of data.

Comment: Thank you. So I will have usernames, address, web links... and some my custom types as links.

Comment: [`UIDataDetector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html) will only recognize certain built-in link types (phone numbers, addresses, URLs, etc.) but won't let you pick arbitrary words to make into links.

Comment: jszumski's statement is correct. I was trying to see if you could do a custom NSDataDetector type with UITextView, but couldn't find any relevant information.